# What maneuvers can every ship do in X-Wing (first edition)?

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

In X-wing first edition, the rules for a stressed ship revealing a red maneuver was revised to the following:

> If a stressed ship reveals a red maneuver, the ship executes a white 2 forward instead.

I assume that every ship can execute a 2 forward maneuver at baseline, or else this rule would be ripe for abuse.  This got me wondering what other maneuvers are present on every ship's maneuver dials.

What maneuvers are available to all ships?  Are there any maneuvers that are green for all ships?

(This is just about small and large ships.  Huge ships are sufficiently different, including not being affected by stress, that they are out of scope for this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ship in X-Wing has a maneuver template that is strictly better than the following:

[image: X-Wing Minimum Manuvers]

That is to say every ship can do all of those maneuvers and more, and every ship has those maneuvers at the listed colors or better (green > white > red).

To call out a couple highlights, every ship has the following:

- A green 2 forward maneuver (this is the only maneuver that is green for all ships)
- The ability to do all 5 standard 2-speed maneuvers (forward, bank, and turn)
- The ability to do a 3 forward and both 3 banks

In this light, the revised rule for executing a red maneuver while stressed is quite reasonable, as not only can every ship do the 2 forward, but a white 2 forward maneuver is strictly worse than the green 2 forward maneuver available to every ship.

Source: https://xwing-miniatures.fandom.com/wiki/Compare_Ship_Maneuvers

The minimum maneuver template can be found in the overlap of just two ships: the A-wing, and the Lambda Shuttle (which makes sense, as these are at the two extremes in terms of ship speed).  After this, you can verify for yourself that every other ship has these maneuvers at the listed color or better.

A-Wing:

[image: A-Wing Maneuver Template]

Lambda Shuttle:

[image]